# Count Futoshiki row solutions

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics, game, puzzle-solver

[Futoshiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki) is a logic puzzle where an \$n×n\$ Latin square must be completed based on given numbers and inequalities between adjacent cells. Each row and column must contain exactly one of each number from \$1\$ to \$n\$ while satisfying the inequalities.

[image]

In a solved Futoshiki puzzle any row (or column) forms a [linear extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of the poset induced by that row's inequalities. Counting linear extensions of posets of this kind is a [polynomial-time problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540334/357390), as opposed to #P-complete for [the general case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46836).

Given the sequence of \$n\ge0\$ symbols between cells of an initially empty Futoshiki row of length \$n+1\$, each of which is one of \$<\$, \$>\$ or \$-\$ (nothing; no constraint), output the number of solutions of that row when considered in isolation. You may use any three distinct symbols for \$<,>,-\$, but your program must pass all test cases below in reasonable time.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
"" -> 1
">" -> 1
"<" -> 1
"-" -> 2
"<>" -> 2
">-" -> 3
"><>" -> 5
"---" -> 24
">->>" -> 10
"><><>" -> 61
"->->-<<>" -> 11340
">-<><--<>><" -> 4573800
"><>><><<<>><>" -> 26260625
">><<>><<>><<>>" -> 120686411
```

Comment: This is a good challenge but the time requirement is unfortunate. It's easy to miss because it's mentioned once inline and there's no [tag:restricted-time] tag. And "reasonable time" is vague. The largest output of ~120 million isn't so big as to definitively rule out exponential-time solutions. My brute-force Python code that branches on all options but stops on a violation takes 25 minutes on my machine -- is that a reasonable time? Other languages and machine are likely faster. If efficiency is important to the challenge, bigger test cases or [tag:restricted-complexity] could have helped.

Comment: Some of the test cases look like fish. Someone answer in ><>

Comment: @xnor done.\${}{}\$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Sorry, I wasn't actually suggesting you change it now given that there's answers relying on it, just so you know for future challenges.

Comment: @xnor Don't worry. I merely saw the sandbox proposal having 4 upvotes and decided to post it as it was at a most opportune time. :)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>110</s>  98 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,m=t=0,j,p)=>s[~~j]?[...s,0].map((_,v)=>m>>++v&1|p*!eval(p+s[j]+v)||f(s,m|1<<v,j+1|0,v))|t:++t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/dCoIwGIbPu4rqILb246bWQei6EJGQ0mhojiY7Gt26TSKxJvSdPu/7vHyyMIU@P26qI/f2UvZ9lQKNm7RLGZZYwVTo7PmU@TGjlGrMctoUCoATNg41QiBkNtyq7ao0RQ0U0pnMkYHWVoPG8iQxWCJumStA2x0Q6vpze9dtXdK6vYIKrNcQLj8XBEu@@OFiEpjjyR9Ovnno9ScDc1yQLx55fCJwfOftEzLlYewPiNEwPMBmFsYNF9j7LzoFSd6ZwcCjmPUv)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (              // f is a recursive function taking:
  s,               //   s = input string of length N
  m =              //   m = bitmask of already used numbers
  t = 0,           //   t = number of solutions
  j,               //   j = pointer in s, initially undefined
  p                //   p = previous number in the permutation
) =>               //
s[~~j] ?           // if there's still something to process:
  [...s, 0]        //   create an array of length N + 1
  .map((_, v) =>   //   for each value at position v in there:
    m >> ++v & 1 | //     increment v; abort if v was already used
    p * !eval(     //     or p is defined and
      p + s[j] + v //       the expression p + s[j] + v
    ) ||           //     is falsy once evaluated as JS code
    f(             //     otherwise, do a recursive call:
      s,           //       pass s unchanged
      m | 1 << v,  //       update m to mark v as used
      j + 1        //       increment j
      | 0,         //       or force it to 0 if it was undefined
      v            //       set p = v
    )              //     end of recursive call
  ) | t            //   end of map(); yield t
:                  // else:
  ++t              //   increment t
```

Comment: Does this pass the last three test cases “in reasonable time”?

Comment: @Jordan 37 seconds, 3 minutes and 23 minutes respectively on my laptop. Now, I've no idea whether that's _reasonable_ or not. (At least it does not compute all \$(n+1)!\$ permutations but aborts as soon as the expression is inconsistent.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 84 bytes

```
t["-"<>#<>"-"]&
t@s_:=t@s=Tr[t/@StringReplaceList[s,"->"|"<>"|"<-"|"--"->"-"]]~Max~1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBCsIwDIbvPkXJYKeF4VW6sAdQEPVWipSx6cAN2XIQ1L16Tbt6yJc/H/kHx/d2cNw3zneq8mwAQVOmSbbNN1zP110lrC6T4bI@89SPt1P7fLim3fczm7kAJPhIKQAFiMFI3S4H91q2/igdNplCUp3JrFW5Kmv1BigUUIAOwJjiTTHTeiCuFxIlm7wY1P@CWBSQTj/hTccVBcWcBr7@Bw)

A fast solution using memoization.  Finishes all test cases in a second.

Without memoization (`t@s=`) it would save 4 bytes, and the last three testcases would take 42 seconds, 4 minutes and 20 minutes respectively on my computer.

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
Count[Sign@*Differences/@Permutations@Range[0,Tr[1^#]],#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBDoMgEAV/hUDioYFY75aQ6AeY2huhDTFgOYgJ4Knx2@mK3mbezi46fc2ik5t0tuiRu3XzSY5u9uLWO2tNMH4ysRaDCcuWIFx9FE/tZyPv9BVk8yZKUaKqPAQHrwQxjqwcE9jc6WiiJBT9MMfHoaEIt4XYgazgZ1dKoQrVAjoMM8clK8FBxXlhfgpjpzHOr/XaYWEt8J7/)

Brute force. Cannot pass the last three testcases in reasonable time.

Takes input as a list, where `>`, `<`, `-` are represented by `1`, `-1`, `_` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

## [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289#9289), <s>72</s> 50 bytes

-28 bytes thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) and [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b).

I wasn't going to post this since it craps out on the last three test cases on ATO but it looks like I'll be in good company anyway, so here it is.

```ruby
->s{[*0..s.sz].pe.ct{|a|s.a?{|t|1>t*=a.po-a[-1]}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbNjts2EAZ69FPMejdrybFlyfvTYBFnkxSbtpcGSIAeargGJdO2Ev2BpDaxLedFesmhPfaBmqfpDCnJsuMEKbpYmORw5uNw5puh_vhT5P7q46fW36fwY0pzyASP8hmHPiyVyuTNYLAI1TL3nSCNB6Rhfvwo9Qcxk4qLwSKN5tPSzhF-K4iYlPDSf8MD1QJ4-lQrLJlcwgg22xbK7rnwU8l7cPbr3avnL1_f4U417UESRqgz43OIuVqms2kcShkmC4h70GU9OPdxG0ChUQN8DGPclzyaO9qDCUygKEYQMxUs0XpqwKQV22N3ohHCOYKcn4PBA5hOJU9m06ml6CAbNkWXiYUsym0A3_HDZIZgDr9nkdXORBpsCu2CPmbGFCvg7AN6ti-Ebdt2AhZF1tkHm849-9AA1Rv6KLuUbvXII8lLgYLbA_coDjbcgMwzLox6MmtVv43AlsFuVTE9jIdEnU6nBzGO5AnzI15tGn8E7gx-P91IR6VT6Sxk7lsDZ2Bv2pbTvbXb8BBe8QV_nzlcBizj1tm5vd0OtG3sLATPLGE7MhVqihSbpVCEVUxDA6mdIiU0V7ngJMms8xsZrrkNjx9DeHDD8jIm3WkiVU2S4AvkCHrfwI2gBxqNJUrWNFHAkhkIjo4lZnu64MpSZXBYKDn8wmJ-J0QqetDOkzAJVcgidH5W48HpJti2ezrEXFiefXCTJYaHIzTzfcHvQ6bCNPmG3JCGyYteprmYBgwdGoF1-8xxbn-zYTRClQbnYwdJzN9bxmwVV6TznDxTKYp11DfFukBkTGiik00dANlv_FrblKBNoQRec1cfCX-vIE8ijg3A2jtfK6IPtKqdrO30LnTprrWsjLfZCo_wVu9gaChP-iYELasC-qyCTFc5wqHDuJqw1lwhVNPMsARLFSR8JsJ7pmojLMSdeQleqlTnLC1G2fwJ0-nT5B1OApqcdEwGslxJaJ9u2JZHUdpDwvjbVEQzTZx9n-cWMcJzXWNZZi7GpCUFwXRehOv183y9bnXG4Sjpdi8f9L2rXvjQu5gURbLdoSFLmQTJVvr4Cn-WTt8tw8jEzgU9h1XIo4PYoV6eqDKyLuj5np7WNXF8JgRb1Sem0Wyqk1ZS10i15E0aJk3DFwyz-ANNv2hNvtQ10G5_fvjPicIOJWoAzoIlqDDmZBImgX707pI85oK40DR9jURLFrXlAGQWhaq1O5UZxpDU6nQadW3pK2O1UQMIdlzpwxHRg3BMWGKFlGeJzLBlwzxiSvGkGk-wmcQZQyaW4wmgg2mAPYiGie3QtTYFgZqipGcK2npKzp5uaGtr3hp6QKI0eFuVP7Gzvg3Vn8wjaqPM-aoZdveIBdxiDuWtkmLBGoBdEVX5N39lQnRzMJpYxlhhpRXe7q3VCbodeuJKmeaFsca6PnJCmT-VikYX0SrmNdEOUqvgqLhD4gfa1Y5uFHqkCG6bnNg76Tgl_1PyxzdlGCfYWsY3BPE_s0mZ_Fri6ls1_UfPMmp05VjvVfLqjnvlsYr9tPpg233J7J9GH0r64Rc8uC9q5gT3Tv1RQx2XvmuOedqs5_nor1zN-4_-GfafyM246zoOvlLriZNxJ1CbghXSYbf4NBXeE9UdMSdL-2zc9ybb7dZYfvqudQpPoI__Hs76NAMXZ4_1zGvpd5geKHpcx3j4eILdmDY9WiBWc7m_cqvVUO_1YKc9NMY9qHUuKsme3pXGQbWG5vCyNibVprrn7qEcgF17JVrD1tU6-yDexSXhnNaH7MDc5lrLKqvLq-8vHrkNu6ZSPRyR19e6Hl6718OrHUL_mMEXVrXzQ_f60fWl57UmrUbydP1o1knNUf0hn8F8XC4nRChDiY8fzfgv)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>95</s> 67 bytes

-22 bytes thanks to Dingus and G B.

```ruby
->s{[*0..s.size].permutation.count{|a|s.all?{|t|1>t*=a.pop-a[-1]}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZLNaoQwFIWhS5_igrvBhCT-1EW1iz6GSMk4ygw4KpO4mKpP0o2U9qHap2nUUWOZQiD33JzzJSF5_7zU-2v_kQVftcyQ__2CQtFEO4KxwOL0lsa4Si_nWnJ5KguclHUhm5a3AvM8f25a2dJQ7gKOq7JCPEI07rpuQv08GCaEgNSgqkJDBURVT2NFDZkK-ZpwkQoIIDIAotgCc1ikg1AsXW4VmRUb1yxY3WwKW7B47Lmz8bkjR9k0J3OW8GDV7ZRsKH9gHr3RtCwZPVsItZ2BYy6brDCi67E3pxz30faJltNNy3Snv1zLYx7xmLsS0L3AP2o5PCOe7zmUGrGhPR5OeXKEQwmtuJ73ZS5atU0FWXSTsZEWh-lL9P00_wI)

Comment: What is GoRuby ? This redirects me to the same page as normal Ruby

Comment: @TKirishima Oops, the link is supposed to be this one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289#9289 TL;DR Goruby is a compact dialect of Ruby.

Comment: Using `ct`/`count` instead of `su`/`sum` (thus eliminating `?1:0`), `[0,m<=>n][t]==t` instead of `t==0||t==(m<=>n)`, and `_1` instead of `|a|a` saves 7 bytes in Goruby and 5 in Ruby.

Comment: 67 bytes: [`->s{[*0..s.size].permutation.count{|a|s.all?{|t|1>t*=a.pop-a[-1]}}}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZLNaoQwFIWhS5_igrvBhCT-1EW1iz6GSMk4ygw4KpO4mKpP0o2U9qHap2nUUWOZQiD33JzzJSF5_7zU-2v_kQVftcyQ__2CQtFEO4KxwOL0lsa4Si_nWnJ5KguclHUhm5a3AvM8f25a2dJQ7gKOq7JCPEI07rpuQv08GCaEgNSgqkJDBURVT2NFDZkK-ZpwkQoIIDIAotgCc1ikg1AsXW4VmRUb1yxY3WwKW7B47Lmz8bkjR9k0J3OW8GDV7ZRsKH9gHr3RtCwZPVsItZ2BYy6brDCi67E3pxz30faJltNNy3Snv1zLYx7xmLsS0L3AP2o5PCOe7zmUGrGhPR5OeXKEQwmtuJ73ZS5atU0FWXSTsZEWh-lL9P00_wI)

Comment: @Dingus Very clever. Thanks!

Comment: @GB Nice! Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 111 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t="",b=1:b and(s+t==""or(s<">">"<"!=t[-1:])*b*f(s[1:])*f(t[:-1])+f(s[1:],t+s[:1],b*-len(s)/~len(t)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BboQgFIb3cwrKChSmog41RrxGF8YFdjQ1YdQIbdJNL9KNm_Y6Xc9t-lRMQ-D9-fne_-DrZ_pwr-OwLN9vruPZfeyU0bfmqpFlTmHMGiXyBunhSmzoFDjjTGyBS1gFflCu4iKvadAEHbHVJjviqpyLmobeYi60VS5q1gTctAOx9PFzrY5S6sc-d-OMDOoHNE5wE9H8hHo2IoVueiLtuzbMnO1kekcw4iXClAKg-vPcTka_tCTAXGHwprkfHIFW1pH-iF_uv3hrEyd4thfFIfgmYnDKQ5W7l4Dy5gU47sl0BUofFG2Mp-QaB3e88IYQSboSHBAOR7lPTS9PSRbtrWt3sZU9XcYykjHMA6v433tcHMlMpkLs__oD)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 118 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t="",b=1:(s<">">"<"!=t[-1:]and(s+t==""or b*f(s[1:])*f(t[:-1])))+(s>""and f(s[1:],t+s[0],b*-len(s)/~len(t)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BboMwEEX3OYXrlR3sFAOhCGFfowvEAhpQLDmAsBupm16kGzbtdbrObTqAUWXZ8_XnzR_562f8cNehn-fvd9fx7HHvpKlvzaVGljmJMWukyIktsIJT4CfpSi7yqu4vxAZOAjFMqDl2xJZgUxCuzLmoKKUBsQpjIJHvMhfYMqxYc-Sm7Ymlz59LdcD67a8dpBmkezSM0AlpfkCaDUiiWz2S9l4bZk52NNoRjLhCmFIApD5N7Wjqt5YcMZcYvHHSvSMwyjqi9_j58YvXMXGAz3hR7IKvIgJH7UptXgzKm2fguCeTBVA-KFwZT6VLHPR44Q0h4mQhOCAcHrVtTc4vcRZuo8t0sZYtPY3SMI1gH1jF_93iojDN0kSI7V9_)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 123 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t="",b=1:(s[:1]!=">">"<"!=t[-1:]and(s+t==""or b*f(s[1:])*f(t[:-1])))+(s>""and f(s[1:],t+s[0],b*-len(s)/~len(t)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BboQgFIb3cwqGFYwwFXWsMcI1ujAutKMpCaNGaJOmSS_SjZv2Ol3PbfpUTEPg_fnf937g62d8dy9DP8_fr67j2f2jk6a-NdcaWeYkxqyRIie2zEV1lFjBKvBRupKLvKr7K7GBk4ANE2pOHXBgUxCuzLmoKKUBsQpjIJHvMhfYMqxYc-Km7YmlD59LdcD6Jzx1kGaQ7tEwQiek-QFpNiCJbvVI2rfaMHO2o9GOYMQVwpQCIPV5akdTP7fkhLnE4I2T7h2BUdYRvcfP91-8jokDfMaLYhd8FRE4aldq82JQ3rwAxz2ZLIDyQeHKeCpd4qDHC28IEScLwQHhcKjt1uTyGGfhNrpMF2vZ0tMoDdMI7gOr-N9bXBSmWZoIsf3rDw)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 165 bytes (@Steffan)

```python
f=lambda s,b=1:s==""or sum((b:=b*(i-len(s))/~i)
*("<"<s[i]and">">s[i+1]and f(s[i+2:])*f(s[:i]))for i in range(len(s)-1))+(s<">"and f(s[1:]))+(s[-1]>"<"and f(s[:-1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BcoMgGIX3OQXDCoykYozNOMA1usi4wEZbZog6YjrTTS_STTbpdbrObfojOF2Ij8d73w_fP-Pn_D70t9v9Onfs-Lh30upLc9bIpY3klZMS42FC7nohpKlkkxDDbNsTR-nTl6GbhGCBhTuZWvdnrLACueV-gzridV7VNPGyMjWlHbAMMj2adP_WkkBinNItcQLqa49Dy3snxmsFE1a_gj2l8bIvnmY9bRgBlNFqg0w6IIkueiTth7ap3bnRmplgxBTClEJAmt3Ujla_tiTBTGLwxsn0M4Fq2hGz4m-PX7zU-AYuFoVYBVtEDo5alQreHlQ0D5BjMVn4gIqgbMnEVOlxcMZENDjfFz7BIMJgUWFqcXjeH7NQ9W2x_AK9zMuszGEeWOL_C7g8K49lwXl41x8)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 174 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,b=1:s==""or sum((b:=b*(i-len(s))/~i)
*((s[i]>"<")*(s[i+1]<">")and f(s[i+2:])*f(s[:i]))for i in range(len(s)-1))+((s[0]<">")and f(s[1:]))+((s[-1]>"<")and f(s[:-1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY-xboMwFEX3fIXlyY_gFBNCI4T9Gx0qBtNAa8kBBKRSl_5Ilyzt2F_pnL_pMzaqOmCu7rv3PPvja3ibX_ruev28zC0_3r5bafW5PmkyxbUUxSQlpf1IpsuZsbqQdcQMt03HJoC7dwObiLHp0VSKlhQiJ7eiKqmioLsTaRcjLSqInCxMBdAizRDTkVF3zw3zLC4Ato6U_C8LrPoBF37HOinQAAi3fnBQ66D9gLwEig0xcU8kOeuBNa_axnY3DdbMjBKuCAXAgDS7sRmsfmpYRLmk6A2j6WaG1bhlZsVfbz90qYkN3i2IchV8ESk6alXKe3tUwTxgjodk5gIqgJIlE1K5w-GMl8EQYp-5BMcIx0P5rdnhfn9MfNW1y-Xn6XmaJ3mK-9Aq_z6PS5P8mGdC-Hf9Ag)

This will surely be outgolfed to oblivion but it finishes all test cases in a second on ato.

Takes "=" instead of "-" because it sits conveniently between "<" and ">" codepointwise.

Uses a divide-and-conquer-ish approach: take the first element recurse into the two leftover halves and multiply their counts with each other and the number of ways they can be merged which is some binomial coefficient.

Comment: you have two places with redundant parens. [170](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY8xboMwGIX3nMLy5J_gFBNCI4R9jQ4Vg2kgteQAAlKpSy_SJUs79DKdc5v-tkEdjB_P732__fk9vM-vfXe7fV3nlh_vP620-lKfNJniWopikpLSfiTT9cJYXcg6YobbpmMTwMOHgU3E2PRsKkVLCpGTW1GVVFHQ3Ym03kiLCiInC1MBtEgzxHRk1N25YYHFBcAWE4nvrlWBRW9z4QesfoH_AMuNnxzQOmA_ICuBYkNM3BNJLnpgzZu2sd1NgzUzo4QrQgEwIM1ubAarXxoWUS4pesNouplhNW6ZWfG3-y_1NbHBiy2iXAX3IkVHrUoFb49qMQ-Y40sycwG1gBKfWVK5w-EZLxdDiH3mEhwjHD8qTM0Oj_tjEqquXfot0PM0T_IU56FV_q-AS5P8mGdChHf9AQ)

Comment: [168](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BboQgGIX3noKwAkem4jh2YoBrdNG4wI5OSRg16jTpphfpxk2b3qbruU1_BNOF-Hi89_3w-T28z699tyxft7llp_tPK62-1meNpqSWvJykxLgf0XS7ElKXso6JYbbpyETpw4ehUUywwGJ6NpXuzlhhBXLH3Qa1xOmsrGjsZGkqSltgGWQ6NOru0hBPYpzSHSTSSgBhq3IorjbjlYIhm1_CntJw3ycHtA7YD8BKaRkhk_RIoqseSPOmbWL302DNTDBiCmFKISDNfmwGq18aEmMmMXjDaLqZQDVpidnwy_0XrzUewcWCEJtgq8jAUZtS3juACuYRciwkcxdQAZSumZAqHA7OmAgG54fcJRhEGCzKT82Pj4dT6quuLdafpxdZkRYZzANL_H8el6XFqcg59-_6Aw) by replacing a multiplication with `and`. and you can save another three by doing `s<"<"` instead of `s[0]<"<"`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Pretty horrific brute force solution, exacerbated by me being so horribly out of practice!
Will crap out on inputs longer than 8 characters.

```
¬³ð á ®ã2 e@OxXqUgY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=rLPwIOEgruMyIGVAT3hYcVVnWQ&input=Ii0%2bLT4tPDw%2bIg)

```
¬³ð á ®ã2 e@OxXqUgY     :Implicit input of string U
¬                       :Split
 ³                      :Push 3 (value is irrelevant, we just need an extra element)
  ð                     :0-based truthy indices (which is all of them as every element is a non-empty string, or 3)
    á                   :Permutations
      ®                 :Map
       ã2               :  Sub-arrays of length 2
          e             :  Does every pair return true
           @            :  When passed through the following function as X, at index Y
            Ox          :    Eval as JavaScript
              Xq        :      Join X with
                UgY     :      Character in U at index Y
                        :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 87 bytes

```
≔⪫--Ｓθ≔⦃⦄η⊞υθＦυ«§≔ηιＥΦ⊖Ｌι∧⁻>§ικ⁻<§ι⊕κ⁺⁺…ικ-✂ι⁺²κＦ⁻§ηιυ⊞υκ»ＦＬθＦΦυ⁼⊕ιＬκ§≔ηκ∨ΣＥ§ηκ§ηλ¹Ｉ§ηθ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVFNSwMxEMVj-ytCThPIHvQktCyUqrBisdCjeFi3aTdsmv1IIkrpL_HSg6In_40Xf00n2S1dMZDA5L2ZN2_m7SvL0yYrU7Xffzi7ii5_z34mxsi1httSaqBRRDlJdOXswjZSr4ExTmo2Gnas7Y6THMO5Mzm4FlqVDQHHyHY4aFkTm-ileIGcE8nJLK3gRiorGrgSWSM2QluxhDuh1zYH6QUmegkzqZ0BGqP-MR-TCw930PgvlOhTMaQxz5wrJIZn-popMc3Lqq3CCY0ovgslM-G_AukiCOAZDQfBRavU7x9zHGPk6LdA6q513BmoEQ1x5xFJ17VLlYF-g75OlxAUyb9JFZzcN7BwG_AD6wPsZBtDFYye-57nuCEL09TYPr_2ft7NU2a6HX8-0OhZ0cfvOB6PT7cFDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @alephalpha's Mathematica answer. The number of solutions for any given string of inequalities is the sum of the numbers of solutions when the highest number is placed in any legal cell (i.e. not to the right of `>` or to the left of `<`). These numbers of solutions are equivalent to the numbers of solutions of a reduced string of inequalities where the cell and its inequalities have been replaced by a separator.

```
≔⪫--Ｓθ
```

Wrap the inequalities in `-`s. This makes the legal highest cells easier to identify.

```
≔⦃⦄η
```

Start collecting lists of reduced strings of inequalities.

```
⊞υθＦυ«
```

Start a breadth-first search with the wrapped input string.

```
§≔ηιＥΦ⊖Ｌι∧⁻>§ικ⁻<§ι⊕κ⁺⁺…ικ-✂ι⁺²κ
```

Get the possible reduced strings of inequalities for this string and save them in the dictionary.

```
Ｆ⁻§ηιυ⊞υκ
```

Add those strings that have not yet been seen to the search for further processing.

```
»ＦＬθＦΦυ⁼⊕ιＬκ
```

Process the strings of inequalities in increasing order of length.

```
§≔ηκ∨ΣＥ§ηκ§ηλ¹
```

Update the dictionary with the total count for this string of inequalities.

```
Ｉ§ηθ
```

Output the total count for the wrapped input string.

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
≔⁺-Ｓθ⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥΦ⁻Ｅθνκ∧∨⁻ι<‹↨κ⁰μ∨⁻ι>›↨κ⁰μ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＩＬυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9BasMwEEX3PYXQagQydBmIMaSFloJDDF4aL1RHcYRt2dZIuUw2WbQ0V-olcoaMmnQRxEjo_a_P1_Hc7JVrRtWfTt_B75LF72WFaFoLRR8QeMIl-7BT8KV3xrYghGSzWD4VAfcQJKtquuxGx2AW7P6yDAOs1RTleLyZ3msHa2MpMIJZMksxHc3KbmHzrxnJeMqJ5hoRXhRq6CR7JjDQPNiyaHt3WsXkRydtf9UJVEMtRAQhNqb-Hl4Vesi1bT3VJ235hZ8N3v_-U_Hk0PP6nGS00jS74Ss) Link is to verbose version of code. Brute force, so the last few test cases will time out on ATO. Explanation:

```
≔⁺-Ｓθ
```

Prepend a `-` to the input string as the first number is not constrained by any previous number.

```
⊞υ⟦⟧
```

Start with a list of no numbers found.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over each constraint.

```
≔ΣＥυＥΦ⁻Ｅθνκ∧∨⁻ι<‹↨κ⁰μ∨⁻ι>›↨κ⁰μ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

For each list so far find all the numbers that satisfy the next constraint and create a new list of lists.

```
ＩＬυ
```

Output the number of lists found.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), Fast: 47 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) / Slow: 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

#### Slow:

```
L‘Œ!IṠnẠ¥ƇV€L
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters - `<->` represented as `-01` respectively and yields the solution count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUcOMo5MUPR/uXJD3cNeCQ0uPtYc9alrj8///fyVDXSBUAgA)** Or see the, truncated [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUcOMo5MUPR/uXJD3cNeCQ0uPtYc9alrj8/9RwxwbXTsgqWtg@KhhbiWQpaChBCSVNK0UgAJZOofbj23SfNS44@ieyP//o5WUdBSU7ECEDYjQBbPAfDsw2w7C0dWF8HTt7KCiQPFYAA) (shows the Link input in parentheses).

###### How?

```
L‘Œ!IṠnẠ¥ƇV€L - Link: list of characters, A, from '-01' (equivalent to '<->' respectively):
L             - length (of A)
 ‘            - increment
  Œ!          - all permutations of [1..that]
    I         - deltas (b-a for each neighbouring pair (a,b) in each list)
     Ṡ        - signs -> 1 if a<b; -1 if a>b
          V€  - evaluate each (of A) as Jelly code -> '-': -1, '0' -> 0, '1' -> 1
        ¥Ƈ    - keep those (of the delta lists) for which:
      n       -   not equal? (vectorises)
       Ạ      -   all?
            L - length
```

---

#### Fast:

```
ḅ3$Ɲ%6ỊTœP€⁸;ḊŻ$}¥/€Ñ€Sȯ1
i@‘ịɗ,Ç$;ɼ0ịƲe?®
Ø0jÇ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers - `<->` represented as `[2,0,1]` respectively and yields the solution count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlZjlWNzVc0e7u4KOTo54FHTmkeNO6wf7ug6ulul9tBSfaDA4YlAIvjEekOuTIdHDTMe7u4@OV3ncLuK9ck9BkDOsU2p9ofWcR2eYZB1uP3/o8Z9djaZjzauA7L/K9nZ2dggsBIA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlZjlWNzVc0e7u4KOTo54FHTmkeNO6wf7ug6ulul9tBSfaDA4YlAIvjEekOuTIdHDTMe7u4@OV3ncLuK9ck9BkDOsU2p9ofWcR2eYZB1uP3/o8Z9djaZjzauOzrp4c4ZjxrmKGgACU0rhUcNc7NUgNqObdIE2nB0T@T//9FKSjoKSnYgwgZE6IJZYL4dmG0H4ejqQni6dnZQUag4UETXBqYBKKoLJOxsoGpAymzAFFjADsyGYqVYAA) (shows the Link input in parentheses).

###### How?

Implements the same algorithm as [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)'s [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252362/53748) - go show some love :)

No built-in cache so this implements one. It's not got particularly great performance because (a) Jelly has no dictionary or hash-map data type, (b) Jelly only has a single register, so I keep values alongside their corresponding keys so it must search through those too (they can never match as keys are lists while values are positive integers), and (c) I went with a golfy implementation which looks up the key twice.

Note: the main Link is the one at the bottom, `Ø0jÇ`.

```
ḅ3$Ɲ%6ỊTœP€⁸;ḊŻ$}¥/€Ñ€Sȯ1 - Link 1, calculate count: list of integers, A, from [0,1,2] (equivalent to '-><' respectively):
ḅ3$Ɲ                      - convert each neighbouring pair from base 3
    %6                    - modulo by six (vectorises)
      Ị                   - insignificant? (effectively is that 0 or 1?)
       T                  - truthy indices
                            -> starts of substrings equivalent to: '->', '<-', '<>', and '--'
                               i.e. possible surrounding chars of the highest value
        œP€⁸              - partition (A) at each of those (discarding the index itself)
                 ¥/€      - reduce each by:
               $}         -   apply to the right hand one:
             Ḋ            -     dequeue
              Ż           -     prefix a zero (equivalent to a '-')
            ;             -   (left one) concatenate (that)
                    Ñ€    - call Link 2 (below) for each (if any)
                      S   - sum
                       ȯ1 - logical OR with one

i@‘ịɗ,Ç$;ɼ0ịƲe?® - Link 2, get count: list of integers, A, from [0,1,2] (equivalent to '-><' respectively):
               ® - recall from the register
                     Our cache: initially zero, but becomes a list of inputs (lists)
                                and outputs (positive integers) with a zero prefix
                                e.g. [0, [2], 1, [2,2], 1, [1], 1, [1,2], 2, ...]
                                         '<'=1   '<<'=1    '>'=1   '><'=2    ...
                                
              ?  - if...
             e   - ...condition: exists?
    ɗ            - ...then: last three links as a dyad - f(A, cache)
i@               -   index (of A) in (the cache)
  ‘              -   increment -> index of the pre-calculated value
   ị             -   index into the cache -> pre-calculated value
            Ʋ    - ...else: last four links as a monad - f(A):
       $         -   last two links as a monad - f(A):
      Ç          -     call Link 1 (above)
     ,           -     (A) paired with that
         ɼ       -     apply to the register & yield:
        ;        -       (register) concatenate (that) -> adds the "key" A (a list) and value 
          0ị     -     0 index into -> gets the value back out

Ø0jÇ - Link 3 (main Link): list of integers, A, from [0,1,2] (equivalent to '-><' respectively):
Ø0   - [0,0] (equivalent to "--")
  j  - join with A
   Ç - call Link 2 (above)
```

---

#### Also:

Fast version taking the characters as given in the question \$51\$ [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page):

```
*Ɲ%87%5ḂTœP€⁸;45;Ḋ}ʋ/€Ñ€Sȯ1
i@‘ịɗ,Ç$;ɼ0ịƲe?®
⁾--jOÇ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r2FxVC3NV04c7mkKOTg541LTmUeMOaxNT64c7umpPdesDBQ5PBBLBJ9YbcmU6PGqY8XB398npOofbVaxP7jEAco5tSrU/tI7rUeM@Xd0s/8Pt/4FyWUCelYJm5P//0UpKOgpKdiDCBkTogllgvh2YbQfh6OpCeLp2dlBRqDhQRNcGpgEoqgsk7GygakDKbMAUWMAOzIZipVgA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) (non-competing<sup>*†*</sup>), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

<sup>*† Non-competing, because the challenge states* "your program must pass all test cases below in reasonable time"*, which this brute-force approach definitely doesn't do. (And yes, I know the challenge doesn't contain a [restricted-time](/questions/tagged/restricted-time) tag, so it isn't a hard requirement.)*</sup>

```
Ćāœεü2I‚øε».V]PO
```

Uses `‹`/`›`/`1` for `<`/`>`/`−` respectively, and takes the input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SNuRxqOTz209vMfI81HDrMM7zm09tFsvLDbA////aKVHDbuUdIDkTjCJyo4FAA) or [verify some of the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlUr/j7QdaTw6@dzWw3uMDq171DDr8I5zWw/t1guLDfD/r6QXpvM/OjpWRyFa6VHDLiUoYyeEYYjg6yBL7wJyDZE5aCoMwfJoagyhKjBMQmhGMSgWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ć             # Enclose the (implicit) input-list; appending its own first item
 ā            # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping), which will
              # be a list in the range [1, input-length + 1] due to the enclose
  œ           # Get all permutations of this list
   ε          # Map each permutation to:
    ü2        #  Create overlapping pairs of the integer-list
      I‚      #  Pair it with the input character-list
        ø     #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
         ε    #  Map over each pair of pair + character:
          »   #   Join the inner pair by spaces, and then both items by newlines
              #   (e.g. [[1,2],"‹"] becomes "1 2\n‹")
           .V #   Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code
   ]          # Close both maps
    P         # Get the product of each inner list
     O        # Sum the list to get the amount of truthy values
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) + itertools, 149 bytes

```rust
use itertools::*;|s|(1..(s.len()as i8+2)).permutations(s.len()+1).filter(|p|p.windows(2).zip(s).all(|(a,&c)|c==1||(a[1]-a[0]).signum()==c-1)).count()
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be415fc1bec6e36040962d4c9497c984)

Can be assigned to a variable of type `fn(&[i8]) -> usize`. It uses this mapping of characters to ints as input:

```rust
'>' 0
'<' 2
'-' 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 130 bytes

```
DgGHI!GR]1=Tgt^2tl.BGtH=bYVhG ab1FdUtHIv@.[\0tH.BNd=k-tHd Xb_1-/*s<>T.<.>Nktk^2tkhH.!k@b_1)))Rb;J.!hlzVcz)=/*Jegim!!xNdN2lN.!hlN;J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwGIDhv@KOE/xMr25DJNr0sIOYFGXRWriYQdBHlH9@Ge/x4X1@0YWwHqWqiWyHjHcjnnKcoJKouNn3TkYXk23sFlX9LuFwXKGCSlvuE1Q22plzlqTxi4kOGAjt0S@7dwqILxejlLamaIC4ae6vM@Vp3NzG@4OQj7Y6n/RfdNGEELElIdgP)

Uses input `<>`  in place of `<>-`.

Okay, so... this is pretty bad. For one thing it's like 17 bytes longer than the current best python, and it's slower. Depending on what "reasonable"  means it may not even meet the requirements. Alright, so why did I bother sharing it? Well because I think the algorithm is cool, and I'm really just amazed I got it to work. It uses a formula presented in this [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060351), I'll give a brief explanation.

So first we can split the sequence along any `-` into some number of subsequences. Our base point for the final answer is then the number of permutations of the whole sequence divided by each subsequences, this is computed with simple factorials. Then all we need is the number of valid subsequence orders. This is where the OEIS formula comes into play, it basically comes down to a particular sum of sequences one less in length than itself. We multiply all of these by the base point and that's our answer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed at the cost of 2 bytes, thanks for noticing. It was actually an issue with the way input was being interpreted.